# Rendering from Blender Game

Tags: game-engine, physics, keyframes

I made a physics simulation in the Blender Game engine. Is there a way to somehow render it as an animation as I normally would with keyframes in Blender internal engine? Or is there a way to convert the positions and rotations of the objects to keyframes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the **Info Area** select **Game** - **Record Animation**. Then start the game engine. This will keyframe all rigid bodies and you can render the scene in BI or cycles.

[image]